# Cross-compiler for Darwin X?

Tags: cross-compilation

Is there a way to cross compile for Mac OS X and iOS on Ubuntu?

I found `mingw-w64` packages and they work well for Windows and it seems I can cross compile for Android as well with `gcc-arm-linux` packages but I couldn't find an equivalent for Darwin X.

I understand there might be some legal issues when dealing with Apple, but Fedora has cross compiler for Darwin X so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

THere are a few project floating around, but [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) seems to be the only one that's being (more or less) maintained now. The build script is a bit rough and it needs an OS X machine to package the SDK, but it does work well.